# Connect to two servers and get the data

Tags: linux, shell

I am writing a script to connect to server machine and get some data from that. My sequence of commands are as follows

```
ssh -tt user@server1 ssh -tt user@server2  
cd dir1/dir2  
ls -1t name* | head 1
```

the result from the last command should be printed after exit from the server

Comment: I did not really understand the question, but it sounds to me that you want to use something like `ssh -t user@server1 'cd dir1/dir2; ls -1t name* | head 1'` as one line to run the commands without staying connected to the server

Comment: @user3639753, Are the `cd` and `ls` commands supposed to run on server2?

Comment: Login to one server  
Login to another server  
Execute some commands  
Return result

Comment: Did i get it right that: the first `ssh` is executed on the local machine, the second `ssh` on server1, the `cd` and `ls` on server2?

Comment: @SamuelKirschner Yes.. That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

To run a command on the other sever, you need to use it as a parameter to ssh.

`man ssh` (abriviated with [...]):

> Synopsis
>
> ssh [...] destination [command]
>
> [...]
>
> If *command* is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of a login shell.

To illustrate In the first step only the second command is converted to this form.

```
ssh -tt user@server1
ssh -tt user@server2 'cd dir1/dir2; ls -1t name* | head 1'
```

now the second one has to be quoted as well and used as parameter to the first login:

```
ssh -tt user@server1 "ssh -tt user@server2 'cd dir1/dir2; ls -1t name* | head 1'"
```

make sure to escape characters that are spacial in double quotes e.g. `"\$"`